# Python 2 way text variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just followed a small tutorial to make a small gui program with pyton. I'm trying to make a python gui programm to set/update the variables from my main python program on a other server.

I'm trying to put some variables in a local file ( to connect to the server ). However i can't seems te make it work, i can acces the variable in the file, i can write to the file but i can't update the variable while the program is running, i want the variable file to be reloaded by my gui python script so that the newest variable will be used. I could also set the local variable to the updated value, but i rather reload the whole file in case other variables have updated aswell.

Python GUI script:

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from os import path
import os
import paramiko
from var import *

vars = 'C:/Users/nick/Desktop/var.py'
window = Tk()

window.title("Welcome to LikeGeeks app")
__file__ = 'C:/Users/nick/.ssh/'
def ppkFile():

    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir= path.dirname(__file__), filetypes = (("Primary Key Files","*.rsa"),("all files","*.*")))
    print(file)
    if file:
        ssh_key = file
        t = open(vars ,'w')
        t.write('ssh_key = \'' + file + '\'')
        t.close()

def readVarFile():
    t = open('C:/Users/nick/Desktop/var.py' ,'r')
    tempstr = t.read()
    t.close()
    print(tempstr)

def checkVar():
    print(ssh_key)

menu = Menu(window)

new_item = Menu(menu,tearoff=0)

new_item.add_command(label='Add Primary key file', command=ppkFile)
new_item.add_command(label='Connect ssh', command=readVarFile)
new_item.add_command(label='Print ssh_key', command=checkVar)
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=new_item)

window.config(menu=menu)


tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

tab_control.add(tab1, text='First')

tab_control.add(tab2, text='Second')

lbl1 = Label(tab1, text= 'label1')

lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0)

lbl2 = Label(tab2, text= 'label2')

lbl2.grid(column=0, row=0)

tab_control.grid(column=0, row=1)
#tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')


#file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir= path.dirname(__file__))
window.mainloop()
```

var.py file:

```
ssh_key = 'C:/Users/nick/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

So when i first check both variables are good, but when i select a new key the text file updates but the local variable doesn't.

Output:

```
readVarFile = ssh_key = 'C:/Users/nick/.ssh/id_rsa'
checkVar = C:/Users/nick/.ssh/id_rsa

ppkFile = C:/Users/nick/.ssh/known_hosts
#Picked a new ssh key

readVarFile = ssh_key = 'C:/Users/nick/.ssh/known_hosts'
#updated to the new value
checkVar = C:/Users/nick/.ssh/id_rsa
#Still the old value
```

I have got it working on a 'dirty' manner:

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from os import path
import os
import paramiko
from importlib import reload
import fileinput


def ppkFile():

    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir= path.dirname(__file__), filetypes = (("Primary Key Files",""),("all files","*.*")))
    print(file)
    if file:
        updateVarFile('__ssh_key__', file)
    refreshVarFromFile()
        #t = open(vars ,'a')
        #t.write('\n' + '__ssh_key__ = \'' + file + '\'')
        #t.close()
    #os.system("ssh -i " + file + " root@94.130.187.163")
    #os.system("ls -al")
    #os.system("pscp -i " + file + " C:/Users/nick/Desktop/var.txt root@94.130.187.163:/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/winvar.py")
    #os.system("ls -al")

def updateVarFile(svar, s):
    print(s)
    content_file = []
    var_file = open((vars) , 'r+')
    for line in var_file:
        if line.startswith(svar):
            content_file.append(svar + ' = \'' + s + '\'\n')
        else:
            content_file.append(line)
    var_file.seek(0)
    var_file.truncate()
    print(content_file)
    var_file.writelines(content_file)
    var_file.close()


def refreshVarFromFile():
    import imp
    f = open(vars)
    global data
    data = imp.load_source('data', vars)
    f.close
    print(data)
    refreshGui()

def refreshGui():
    #global sshkey
    #sshkey.set(data.__ssh_key__)
    sshText.delete(0,END)
    sshText.insert(0, data.__ssh_key__)
    sshHostText.delete(0,END)
    sshHostText.insert(0, data.__ssh_host__)
    sshUserText.delete(0,END)
    sshUserText.insert(0, data.__ssh_user__)
    tab2.update()

def checkVar():
    print(data.__ssh_key__)

def connect():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(data.__ssh_host__, username=data.__ssh_user__, key_filename= data.__ssh_key__ )
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cd /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin')
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls -al')
    print(stdout.readlines())
    ssh.close()

def validateSSHAUTH():
    updateVarFile('__ssh_key__' , sshText.get())
    updateVarFile('__ssh_user__' , sshUserText.get())
    updateVarFile('__ssh_host__' , sshHostText.get())
    refreshVarFromFile()
def saveConfig():
    if chkDoSomething_state.get() == 0:
        disableFunction('doSomething')
    else:
        print('enable function')
        enableFunction('doSomething')

def disableFunction(s):
    content_file = []
    disable = False
    var_file = open((bot) , 'r+')
    for line in var_file:
        if disable:
            if line.startswith('    ' or '  '):
                content_file.append('#' + line)
            else:
                disable = False
                content_file.append(line)
        else:
            if line.startswith('def ' + s):
                disable = True
                content_file.append('#' + line)
            else:
                content_file.append(line)
    var_file.seek(0)
    var_file.truncate()
    print(content_file)
    var_file.writelines(content_file)
    var_file.close()

def enableFunction(s):
    content_file = []
    enable = False
    var_file = open((bot), 'r+')
    for line in var_file:
        if enable:
            if line.startswith('#    ' or '#    '):
                content_file.append(line.replace('#',''))
            else:
                enable = False
                content_file.append(line)
        else:
            if line.startswith('#def ' + s):
                enable = True
                content_file.append(line.replace('#',''))
            else:
                content_file.append(line)
    var_file.seek(0)
    var_file.truncate()
    print(content_file)
    var_file.writelines(content_file)
    var_file.close()

vars = 'C:/Users/nick/Desktop/var.txt'
bot = 'C:/Users/nick/Desktop/var2.txt'
window = Tk()
window.title("Chatbot managment app")
__file__ = 'C:/Users/nick/.ssh/'
menu = Menu(window)

new_item = Menu(menu,tearoff=0)

new_item.add_command(label='Add Primary key file', command=ppkFile)
new_item.add_command(label='Connect ssh', command=connect)
new_item.add_command(label='Reload', command=refreshVarFromFile)
menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=new_item)

window.config(menu=menu)


tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

tab_control.add(tab1, text='First')

tab_control.add(tab2, text='SSH-AUTH')

lbl1 = Label(tab1, text= 'label1')

lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0)
chkDoSomething_state = BooleanVar()
chkDoSomething_state.set(True)
chkDoSomething = Checkbutton(tab1, text='Enable doSomething', var=chkDoSomething_state)
chkDoSomething.grid(column=0,row=1)
configFunctionBtn = Button(tab1, text="Save config", command=saveConfig)
configFunctionBtn.grid(column=1, row=1)
lbl2 = Label(tab2, text= 'SSH-key path :')

lbl2.grid(column=0, row=0)
#sshkey = StringVar()
#sshkey.set(data.__ssh_key__)

sshText = Entry(tab2,width=50)
sshText.grid(column=1, row=0)

sshUserLbl = Label(tab2, text='SSH user :')
sshUserLbl.grid(column=0,row=1)
sshUserText = Entry(tab2,width=50)
sshUserText.grid(column=1,row=1)
sshHostLbl = Label(tab2, text='SSH host :')
sshHostLbl.grid(column=0,row=2)
sshHostText = Entry(tab2, width=50)
sshHostText.grid(column=1, row=2)

validatAuthBtn = Button(tab2, text="Update SSH credentials", command=validateSSHAUTH)
validatAuthBtn.grid(column=1,row=3)

#lbl3 = Label(tab2, textvariable=sshkey)
#lbl3.grid(column=1, row = 0)

tab_control.grid(column=0, row=1)
#tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
refreshVarFromFile()
#file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir= path.dirname(__file__))
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your `readVarFile` has no effect other than printing.  Is that what you expected?

Comment: yes the readVarFile is to check if the text file is updated, the checkVar is to check if the local file is updated.

Comment: OK, but what code do you *expect* to update `ssh_key` or (re)apply the `vars` file?  (Incidentally, `vars` is a Python builtin; avoid shadowing it.)

Comment: the ppkFile() should update the var file, i had no way to refresh my local vars thats the problem i had, i found a big work around to do it but i'm not sure if it can be done better.

Comment: You haven’t said what is “dirty” about your approach.  Unless you make your GUI a class of which several instances can exist simultaneously (which is a fine idea!), using `global` (and/or wrappers like `BooleanVar`) is about as good as it gets.  If it really is just a matter of style suggestions, this is a question for Code Review.